# If $B$ be a $3\times 1$ column matrix and $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix such that $B^TAB=O$ for all $B$ then prove that $A$ is skew symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $B$ be a $3\times 1$ column matrix and $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix such that $B^TAB=O$ for all $B$ then prove that $A$ is skew symmetric.

It is easy to see that $B^TAB$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix but after this I am not able to do further. Another way is assume $B$ and $A$ and then multiply and put it equal to $0$ but that is way too lengthy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $B=e_j$, where $e_j$ is $j$-th vector of the canonical base, then $$0=B^TAB=a_{jj}.$$
If $B=e_j+e_i$ with $i\not=j$ then
$$0=B^TAB=a_{jj}+a_{ij}+a_{ji}+a_{ii}=a_{ij}+a_{ji}.$$
Therefore $A=-A^T$.
The property holds also after replacing the dimension $3$ with any positive integer $n$.